# True crypt auto mounting on start-up does not work

Tags: truecrypt

since yesterday my true-crypt partition do not automount on startup with my OS every time (sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't).

- Yes they are set as system favorites and the checkbox mount on startup is set.
- Yes they have the same password, typed with the same (EN INTL) layout.
- Yes it worked somehow before a few times.

Thanks for the help.

edit: 
OS: Windows 8

**Update**
It seems only not to work from cold starts.

warm starts seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this problem on my Windows 8 laptop. I tracked the problem to the new shutdown process with Windows 8. It won't do a full shutdown/startup when you do, only some sort of hybrid shutdown (https://superuser.com/questions/496241/are-there-downsides-to-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown)

I found that if I use the normal Charm -> Settings -> Power -> Shutdown, it would fail to load  the encrypted partition when I got to the desktop.

However, if you use the command line "shutdown.exe /s /t 0" to shutdown, it will reliably load the next time you start up.

I was forced to fix it this way because my Dropbox was on the encrypted partition, and Dropbox would complain that it couldn't find the folder anymore (same with Google Drive and SkyDrive, only worse).

This might fix that problem, but I haven't tried it yet (http://www.askvg.com/fix-windows-8-restart-and-shutdown-problems-by-disabling-hybrid-shutdown-feature/)

Answer (score 2):

Win 8.x seams to offer special shutdown option for a fast restart. This leads also to another special file on the boot driver (besider hypee and page). Therefore the "cold restart" is  not a real cold start it's something like hypernation "light".

In the power options you may try to disable the option "turn fast startup (recommended)" selection.

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative to disabling hybrid boot/shutdown. You can also get it to work consistently if you go to TrueCrypt, Favorites, Organize System Favorite Volumes and then tick the option to *Allow only administrators to view and dismount system favorite volumes*.
[Source](https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/8).

Comment: Had this exact same problem and this worked for me, thanks!